# liferay validate password from a custom portlet

Tags: liferay

I would like to check a password inside a custom portlet.

I have seen this in UserLocalServiceImpl:

```
PasswordPolicy passwordPolicy = passwordPolicyLocalService.getDefaultPasswordPolicy(companyId);
PwdToolkitUtil.validate(companyId, 0, password1, password2, passwordPolicy);
```

I have tried to use it in a custom portlet... I could instiantate passwordPolicy, but I have not access to use PwdToolkitUtil.... the error is "The import com.liferay.portal.secutiry.pwd.PwdToolkitUtil. cannot be resolved".

Where is the problem? is there an alternative to check passwords with portal policy from a custom portlet?

Comment: Would you please explain better what you're trying to do? Are you trying to check if a user entered her own password correctly, if a password is good according to a password policy, or what?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following class/method. Needs a userId and a password (not encrypted, just  plain text).

```
com.liferay.portal.service.PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil

public boolean isSameAsCurrentPassword(long userId, String newClearTextPwd)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use as:

```
PasswordTrackerLocalServiceUtil.isValidPassword(long userId, String newClearTextPwd)
```

this API will be check Liferay PasswordPolicies

Answer (score 0):

`PwdToolkitUtil` is not in the API. Thus, you can look at its source code and implement the equivalent functionality yourself. There's not a lot of code in the class, so duplicating it won't probably be too bad.

Comment: Is there any equivalent method that allows me to use Portal password validation? I hate having duplicate code..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Liferay 7.1

```
    @Override
    protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
                                       ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {

String password1 = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "password1", "");
String password2 = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "password2", "");

     try {
                ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                long userId = UserLocalServiceUtil.authenticateForBasic(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), authType, login, current);
                PasswordPolicy passwordPolicy = PasswordPolicyLocalServiceUtil.getPasswordPolicyByUserId(userId); //.getDefaultPasswordPolicy(companyId);
                ClassLoader portalClassLoader = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
                Class<?> pwdToolkitUtilClass = portalClassLoader.loadClass("com.liferay.portal.security.pwd.PwdToolkitUtil");
                MethodKey methodKey = new MethodKey(pwdToolkitUtilClass, "validate", long.class, long.class, String.class, String.class, PasswordPolicy.class);
                PortalClassInvoker.invoke(methodKey, themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), userId, password1, password2, passwordPolicy);
     } catch (UserPasswordException e) {
                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, e.getClass(), e);
     }
    }
```